# Displaying random entry from database to my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have successfully built a MYSQL database and scraped a bunch of information into it. The issue I am having is I am really struggling to understand how I want to display say, 1 random entry from that database into my view. I have been reading up on MVC and rendering, but I am clearly missing something. I would like to show you what I have thus far and hopefully get some pointers on where to go from here. I think I am really struggling with the views, as it is currently blank!

Thanks!

My model:

```
class Sandwich < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :country, :description, :image, :name
  def self.random_sandwich
Sandwich.find(:first, :order => "RAND()")
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
class SandwichesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /sandwiches
  # GET /sandwiches.json
  def index
    @sandwich = Sandwich.random_sandwich

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @sandwiches }
    end
  end

  # GET /sandwiches/1
  # GET /sandwiches/1.json
  def show
    @sandwich = Sandwich.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @sandwich }
    end
  end

  # GET /sandwiches/new
  # GET /sandwiches/new.json
  def new
    @sandwich = Sandwich.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @sandwich }
    end
  end

  # GET /sandwiches/1/edit
  def edit
    @sandwich = Sandwich.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /sandwiches
  # POST /sandwiches.json
  def create
    @sandwich = Sandwich.new(params[:sandwich])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @sandwich.save
        format.html { redirect_to @sandwich, notice: 'Sandwich was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @sandwich, status: :created, location: @sandwich }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @sandwich.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /sandwiches/1
  # PUT /sandwiches/1.json
  def update
    @sandwich = Sandwich.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @sandwich.update_attributes(params[:sandwich])
        format.html { redirect_to @sandwich, notice: 'Sandwich was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @sandwich.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /sandwiches/1
  # DELETE /sandwiches/1.json
  def destroy
    @sandwich = Sandwich.find(params[:id])
    @sandwich.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to sandwiches_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to order with random, and then find first item.
Smth like this:

```
Sandwich.order("RAND()").first
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be slower. Because it is randomizing all data and picking the first one.

There is another approach. Generate a random number between 0 and total sandwiches - 1. Use that number as offset to get the random sandwich.

```
random_number = rand(Sandwich.count)
random_sandwich = Sandwich.limit(1).offset(random_number)
```